# I have made this blazor server app. I am using OpenApiSecurityScheme( ) for authorization, when i open my web api I am unable to authorize

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, blazor, openapi

[Swagger Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC3KD.png)

I have made this blazor server app. I am using OpenApiSecurityScheme( ) for authorization, when i open my web api I am unable to authorize. I get Bearer error="invalid_token" . I use the secret key from appsettings.json to authorize. Here is my Startup.cs

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews()
             .AddNewtonsoftJson(setupAction =>
             {
                 setupAction.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                    new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
             })
             .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();

        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

        services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();

        services.AddSwaggerGen(setupAction =>
        {
            setupAction.SwaggerDoc(
                "TodoListOpenAPISepcification",
                new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo()
                {
                    Title = "TodoList API",
                    Version = "1",
                    Description = "Through this API you can access todos lists and todos",
                    License = new OpenApiLicense
                    {
                        Name = "MIT License",
                        Url = new Uri("https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT")
                    }
                }); ;

            OpenApiSecurityScheme securityDefinition = new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
            {
                Name = "Bearer",
                BearerFormat = "JWT",
                Scheme = "bearer",
                Description = "Specify the authorization token.",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
            };
            setupAction.AddSecurityDefinition("jwt_auth", securityDefinition);

            OpenApiSecurityScheme securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference()
                {
                    Id = "jwt_auth",
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                }
            };
            OpenApiSecurityRequirement securityRequirements = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
            {
                {securityScheme, new string[] { }},
            };
            setupAction.AddSecurityRequirement(securityRequirements);

            //Collect all referenced projects output XML document file paths  
            var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var xmlDocs = currentAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()
                .Union(new[] { currentAssembly.GetName() })
                .Select(a => Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(currentAssembly.Location), $"{a.Name}.xml"))
                .Where(File.Exists).ToList();

            foreach (var d in xmlDocs)
            {
                setupAction.IncludeXmlComments(d);
            }


        });

        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:Secret"));

        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
        

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(setupAction =>
        {
            setupAction.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/TodoListOpenAPISepcification/swagger.json", "TodoList API");
            setupAction.RoutePrefix = "swagger";

            setupAction.DefaultModelExpandDepth(2);
            setupAction.DefaultModelRendering(Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.ModelRendering.Model);
            setupAction.DocExpansion(Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.DocExpansion.None);
        });

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

    

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

       
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the secret key is different from the JWT bearer token. Are you generating your own JWT or using an identity provider like `Azure AD`, `AWS Cognito`, `Auth0`, etc. (there are tons of identity providers)?

Comment: Why don't you use some example from tutorials ?

Comment: Thank you for replies I found the way to get the token. I wasn't using Authenticate method using username and password to get the token in Swagger UI.